# VBScript Guess a number

Tags: vbscript

So I am at a bit of a loss. I have been working on this script for a "Guess a Number" game for a class and so far I have been successful. Now the assignment requires that when the user guesses either too high or too low it should give them better clues as to how far away they are.

If, for example, the user is 50 numbers away it should notify them they are cold. If they are 30 numbers away they are warm, 10 numbers away they are hot...

I can't figure that part out.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Initialization Section

Option Explicit

Const cGreetingMsg = "Pick a number between 1 - 100"

Dim intUserNumber, intRandomNo, strOkToEnd, intNoGuesses

intNoGuesses = 0

'Main Processing Section

'Generate a random number
Randomize
intRandomNo = FormatNumber(Int((100 * Rnd) + 1))

'Loop until either the user guesses correctly or the user clicks on     Cancel
Do Until strOkToEnd = "yes"

  'Prompt user to pick a number
  intUserNumber = InputBox("Type your guess:",cGreetingMsg)
  intNoGuesses = intNoGuesses + 1

  'See if the user provided an answer
  If Len(intUserNumber) <> 0 Then

    'Make sure that the player typed a number
    If IsNumeric(intUserNumber) = True Then

      'Test to see if the user's guess was correct
      If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) = intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Congratulations! You guessed it. The number was " & _
          intUserNumber & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "You guessed it " & _
          "in " & intNoGuesses & " guesses.", ,cGreetingMsg
        strOkToEnd = "yes"
      End If

      'Test to see if the user's guess was too low
      If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) < intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Your guess was too low. Try again", ,cGreetingMsg
        strOkToEnd = "no"
      End If

      'Test to see if the user's guess was too high
      If FormatNumber(intUserNumber) > intRandomNo Then
        MsgBox "Your guess was too high. Try again", ,cGreetingMsg
        strOkToEnd = "no"
      End If

    Else
      MsgBox "Sorry. You did not enter a number. Try again.", ,     cGreetingMsg
    End If

  Else
    MsgBox "You either failed to type a value or you clicked on Cancel.     " & _
      "Please play again soon!", , cGreetingMsg
    strOkToEnd = "yes"
  End If

Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is probably off topic for S.O. I will give you a hint anyway because I have been in your shoes once...

Does this ring a bell on?

```
coldThresHold = 20

If userNumber = intRandomNo + coldThresHold Then YouGuessed()
Else If userNumber > intRandomNo + coldThresHold Then YouAreCold()
Else If userNumber > intRandomNo Then YouAreHot()
Else If userNumber < intRandomNo - coldThresHold Then YouAreCold()
Else userNumber < intRandomNo Then YouAreHot()
```